# Can I upgrade Maximo integration framework from version 7.5 to version 7.6?

Tags: java, web-services, maximo, maximo-anywhere

During upgrade Maximo (7.5 to 7.6). I would like after upgrading the integrated services are not affected.
What needs to be noted during the upgrade?
Eg: About Global file system, jaxws, Axis, SOAP version
Can you help me.

Comment: This information must be available in the release notes?

Comment: Yes, The documentation only shows changes when upgrading to the new version without specifying how to do it. For example, during the upgrade process, what configuration or modifications for MIF (Maximo Integration Framework)?

Comment: Can you help me? Thanks